# uber/react-map-gl getMap & exposed Mapbox API

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, uber-api, react-map-gl

I'm using the following code snippet to try to access the MapBox API from uber  react-map-gl: 4.0.2 using mapbox-gl v0.50.0.

```
 import MapGL from 'react-map-gl';
 export default class App extends Component 
 {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
   this.mapRef= React.createRef();
   }
   componentDidMount() 
   {
      let data = this.mapRef.getMap().getBounds(); <----
   } 
   render() {
    <MapGL
    {...viewport}
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    mapStyle={MapStyle}
    onViewportChange={this._updateViewport}
    ref={map => this.mapRef = map}
    mapboxApiAccessToken={TOKEN} >
   }
 }
```

if I try to access any other methods like getStyle/getSource and others raise an error  "is not a function" & "Cannot read property 'version' of undefined". Am i Doing something wrong or Not all MapBox Api methods are not available through the getMap() method ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you can get the `map` object correctly then all the functions should be exposed including `getStyle`. `getSource` didn't work for me either, it could be that using mapStyle is not counted as a source? Not sure about this last bit.

Comment: The getMap() function is inherited from static map, according to the react-map-gl docs. that's the reason you have no access to getStyle or getSource

Answer (score 0):

I use this to get the initial map boundaries.

```
    getMapBoundaries = () => {
    // Get map boundaries
    const myMap = this.mapRef.getMap(); 
    console.log(myMap.getBounds());
    const mapBoundaries = myMap.getBounds();
    this.setState({ mapBoundaries })
  }

  componentDidMount = () => this.getMapBoundaries();
```

I also noticed that the import for 'react-map-gl' should be

```
import ReactMapGL from 'react-map-gl';
```

Why the error? 
It seems you are not using a return function in the componentDidMount method.